# How do I manage Attachments (View / Delete)

Tags: xpages

I am able to add a file upload control to my page and add attachments.  But how do I manage them?   View , delete?

I added a computed field to my xpage and make the attachments field the source and set the field as HTML.   I get a bunch of entries like (See attached file: abc.pdf).  But that does not seem to do what I want.

Is there an easy way to manage these attached files?

Comment: "File Download" control?

Comment: Instead of attaching docs to the main notesdocument, I create children docs (1 per attachment) and then use a repeat control to source them to users.  This also allows me to add attachments without doing a full refresh of my xpage - instead my upload control is in an iframe and THAT is full refreshed.  To delete the user clicks an edit button which adds a delete X icon to the attachment.  When that is clicked, the child doc is deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind a file download control to the same data the upload control is bound to. One of the attributes this component supports is a boolean for whether to allow deletion. You can also choose which attributes of each file it displays (MIME type, size, etc.).

Comment: Thanks that was easy.  Not sure why it didn't dawn on me.  This cold really has me. I'm just not thinking clearly.  Three weeks now!   And I fly out for the Connect Conference on Saturday.  This should be fun. :)  Is there a way to calculate the URLS generated by the control?   I am currently using the old method of using a view and $File url.

Comment: Stephan has a good explanation of the URL syntax here: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-86QKNM

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with having an repeat control repeat over the filenames and generate links directly to those files where on the links there are event handlers which do a remove or view ?